# Append new data to shared Excel workbook from Access

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

I am trying to run an append query either through the JET engine or through VBA directly, it doesn't matter, and I keep running into an error.  The workbook is shared and is located on a network drive, both of which I can't change.  I would like to process new data in an Access db and then append the results to that Excel workbook.

I keep getting this error "Operation must use an updateable query".  I originally was appending data that was using `JOIN` query, however I read that could have been the problem.  Now I take the data directly from a table and try to append it to the workbook but I am still getting the same result.  Any thoughts on how to resolve?

Below is the SQL I'm using:

```
INSERT INTO tbl_link_excel_biglist ( SHAW, Debtor, Address, City, County, State ) 
SELECT tbl_biglist_new_data.SHAW, tbl_biglist_new_data.Debtor, 
       tbl_biglist_new_data.PROP_ADDRESS_LINE1, tbl_biglist_new_data.PROP_CITY, 
       tbl_biglist_new_data.PROP_COUNTY_CODE, tbl_biglist_new_data.PROP_STATE, 
FROM tbl_biglist_new_data;
```

More I'm reading online I'm starting to believe this is not allowed in MS Access (2007).

Comment: What is `tbl_link_excel_biglist`? Is this a link to the shared Excel workbook? If so, does it have the right permissions for you to append data?

Comment: Yes it is a shared linked Excel workbook on a network.  I've asked around to some of my MS/VBA guys I know and they are confirming that writing to an Excel file via linked table is not possible.  Very surprising, I would think with prominence of Excel for many people that MS would make this possible.

Comment: Some options I've found are open an instance of Excel and programmatically writing data from the recordset (not sure I'm skilled enough for that), import & append the data in Access then overwriting the entire file, or export the new records in another file and have someone manually append to the Excel file.

Comment: The recordset is the way to go here - once you're used to the syntax, it's surprisingly easy, and there are plenty of examples here in stackoverflow (it's where I learnt most of what I now know about recordsets and Access-Excel communication)

Comment: My end goal on this project is to move the team to a back-end db instead of Excel.  Right now I'm creating the data manipulation tool so once that is complete I'll revisit the question at hand but I imagine it will be a lot easier and more efficient when doing so with a db back-end.